# passing two parameters to exist? in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a friendships model, friendships is a join table that contains a `user_id` a `friend_id` and a status (which is a string). In the create method for the friendship I need to do some validation and check that a friendship doesn't exist already between that user and that `friend` to do this I've called:

```
unless userID == friendID or Friendship.exists?(userID, friendID)
```

However exists? throws this error when create is called:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)):
```

I can't correctly do the validation without checking the `userID` and `friendID` exist in one friendship. My question is is there a better way I can do this not using exists? or is there a way I can pass two parameters to the exists? method in rails.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@userid = any_user_id
@friendid = any_friend_id
(@userid == @friendid || Friendship.where(user_id: @userid,friend_id: @friendid).present?) ? true : false
```

OR if you want to use `exists?`:

```
(@userid == @friendid || Friendship.exists?(user_id: @userid,friend_id: @friendid)) ? true : false
```

this will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Wouldn't the ` ? true : false` would be superfluous here? `exists?` returns `true` or `false` already. Same with `present?`.

Comment: but you have '||' with another condition maybe this one will return false and also `Friendship.exists?(user_id: @userid,friend_id: @friendid)` will return false this is not 1 condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rails validation methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) to do this.

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ensure that user/friend combo does not already exist
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: friend }

  # ensure that friend != user
  validate :friend_is_not_user

  # other Friendship model code

  def friend_is_not_user
    if self.friend == self.user
      errors.add(:user, 'cannot be friends with his or her self.')
    end
  end
end
```